Find the largest possible ways to form a set of codes such that any two codes in the set must differ in at least 2 positions
Problem: You are tasked with creating a set of barcodes for labeling, where each barcode is a string of $k$ letters $k \geq 1$, using only the characters $ A, B, C, D $. The requirement is that any two barcodes in the set must differ in at least 2 positions when compared letter-by-letter. For example, the following two strings differ in 3 positions: $ABCD$ and $ADBC$.
You need to find: Given a fixed value of  $k$ (length of the barcodes), what's the largest number of barcodes in the set that follows the rule above?
Example
Barcode sets:

$\{ABC, BAC, CAB, DAB\}$: This set is valid and has four barcodes.

$\{ABC, BAC, CAB, DAB, DAC\}$: This set is not valid since the
strings $BAC$ and $DAC$ differ in only 1 position $A$ and $D$.


My attempt:

For $k = 1$, we can only pick one of the four $\{A, B, C, D\}$
strings as the barcode set.
For $k = 2$, we can pick four barcodes. One example is $\{AA, BB, CC,
   DD\}$.

Question: Is there any general way to solve for $k \ge 3$.

Is $AACC$ an allowed barcode, or must each letter appear exactly once?

@MJD Your example is valid. In the problem, each letter can appear more than one.

Are you sure the first set is valid? It seems as though $CAB$ and $DAB$ don’t satisfy your properties.

HINT [FINISH #4]:

For each word $W$ of length $k$ on the alphabet $\{A,B,C,D\}$, define $S(W) = \#\{$$A$'s in $W\}$ $+$ $2\#\{$$B$'s in $W\}$ $+$ $3\#\{$$C$'s in $W\}$ $+$ $4\#\{$$D$'s in $W\}$. Call $S(W)$ the value of $W$.

Then take for your set of the code-words $W$ to be the set
$\{$words $W$ of length $k$ on $\{A,B,C,D\}$ such that the value $S(W)$ of $W$ is a multiple of $4\}$. This will give you $\frac{1}{4}$-fraction of the set $\{$words of length $k$ on the aphabet, $\{A,B,C,D\} \ \}$ as code-words in your set of code-words. [Indeed, for any word $W_{k-1}$ of length $k-1$ on the alphabet $\{A,B,C,D\}$, exactly one of the $4$ words $AW_{k-1}, BW_{k-1}, CW_{k-1}$, and $DW_{k-1}$ has value that is a multiple of $4$.]

Then note that you cannot do better than a $\frac{1}{4}$-fraction, as for any word $W_{k-1}$ of length $k-1$ on the alphabet $\{A,B,C,D\}$, only one of the $4$ resulting words $AW_{k-1}, BW_{k-1}, CW_{k-1}$, and $DW_{k-1}$ can be in any set of code-words, because these $4$ words all differ from each other in only one place.

I leave it to you to establish that indeed $\{$words $W$ of length $k$ on $\{A,B,C,D\}$ such that the value $S(W)$ of $W$ is a multiple of $4\}$ indeed satisfies the desired properties, that any two words in this set differ by at least $2$ places.



(That seems much more of a solution than an hint.)

@CalvinLin it started out as a hint but then I realized that some of the details are tricky too, so I established those

Can you explain your idea of choosing $W$ such that $S(W) = 0$ mod 4?
